# RestSharp double-nested elements not being Deserialized

Tags: xml, serialization, restsharp

So I am attempting to use the default XmlDeserializer from RestSharp to deserialize the following XML structure. For the life of me, I am unable to get the 'Picks' to be deserialized at all.

```
<PlayerList>
   <Player>
      <PlayerName>Name</PlayerName>
      <PlayerRank>5</PlayerRank>
      <Picks>
         <PickID>1</PickID>
         <Status>Active</Status>
         <CreatedDate>2012-08-30 09:43:38</CreatedDate>
      </Picks>
      <Picks>
         <PickID>2</PickID>
         <Status>Disabled</Status>
         <CreatedDate>2012-08-30 09:49:33</CreatedDate>
      </Picks>
   </Player>
</PlayerList>
```

The closest I ever came was to define them in the "Player" class as...

```
public class Player {
    /*other properties*/
    public List<Picks> Picks { get; set; }
}
```

Which did return a single "Picks" object with all of its properties set to null (or DateTime minimum).

What is the proper way to structure the serializable C# classes to get the data returned from each of the Picks? I wonder if it has something to do with the "Picks" objects having a plural name...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Eventually realized what the issue was with this. The change necessary to get this to work was to make these changes to the "Player" class...

```
public class Player {
    /* other properties */
    List<Picks> PickList { get; set; }
}
```

The issue was occurring because RestSharp was confused because the Property's name ("Picks") was the same as the Object Type ("Picks") that it was trying to deserialize.